# Generic class and IEquatable problems

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, interface, nunit

I want a generic class to implement the IEquatable<T> interface. The class has data items of type T. For the generic class to be equatable the data items need to be that as well.

Here is my generic class:

```
public class V<T> : IEquatable<V<T>> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    public V(T[] Value)
    {
        this.Value = Value;
    }

    T[] Value { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(V<T> other)
    {
        if (Value.Count() != other.Value.Count()) return false;

        for (int i = 0; (i < Value.Count()) && i < other.Value.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (!Value[i].Equals(other.Value[i])) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And here is the problem.
When I compile the above generic class I get the following message.

> GenericArguments[0], 'T' on 'Myspace.Generic.V`1[T]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.

Where do I make the mistake in my reasoning or what is wrong with my generic class?

Note:
When I leave `IEquatable<V<T>>` out at the generic class and the code for `public bool Equals(V<T> other)` intact then the generic class compiles and is usable. Except for detecting IEquitable by the compiler.

```
public class V<T> where T : IEquatable<T>
{
```

The above code works but instances of `V<T>` are no longer recognised as IEquitable

Note2:
Thanks to dasblinkenlight for trying this code in a solution on its own I found out that it is most likely a configuration problem and not a coding problem. I now consider this specific question as answered but I've not yet identified my configuration problem.

Note3:
The actual cause of the problem is an NUnit test module that loads the dll through an accessor. Changing the test procedures is required but `IEquatable<V<T>>` is now used wihtout any problems.

Problem Solved.

Comment: BTW, it would be normal to also override Equals and GetHashCode in this scenario, to avoid inconsistent equality.

Comment: To Marc Gravell: Thanks for the tip. The code above just isolates the problem I have so its a bit short on other issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your generic class. Something is wrong with the class that you are passing as its generic parameter `T`. Namely, `SomeClass`, the class that you pass in `V<SomeClass>` does not implement `IEquitable<SomeClass>`.

Your `V<T>` class requires `T` to be an implementation of `IEquitable<T>`. You need it in order to check element-by-element equality of arrays using the `Value[i].Equals(other.Value[i])` expression. If whatever class that you use as `V<T>`'s generic parameter is not equitable to itself, the compiler would complain.

Comment: The compiler gives the warning on compiling the generic class. I do not instantiate V<T> anywhere in the code yet. And I do declare that T must implement IEquitable.
If I try to instantiate V<SomeClass> where SomeClass does not have an implementation of IEquitable I get a warning at that point, not on the generic class.

Comment: @PapaAtHome When I compile your class by itself, it compiles perfectly without a warning ([link](http://ideone.com/saHQw8) to ideone).

Comment: I now have two solutions, the original one *with* the problem and a new one with only this generic type in it *without* the problem. Looks like a configuration problem now.

Comment: The actual cause of the problem is an NUnit test module that loads the dll through an accessor. Changing the test procedures is required but IEquatable<V<T>> is now used wihtout any problems.

Comment: @PapaAtHome Excellent! If you are no longer looking for an improved solution to this problem, consider accepting this answer to let others know that your problem is solved.